# Can a known change in both axes of a polynomial function be used to find the value of the independent variable?

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have a polynomial function of one variable, $d = f(t)$. I have a known change in t which causes a known change in $d$. What I want to find is the total $t$. Is there a way of solving this other than trial and error?

In other words, I have a known polynomial $f$ and two known quantities $a$ and $b$ such that $f(t+a)−f(t)=b$, and I want to find $t$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that you have a known polynomial $f$ and two known quantities $a$ and $b$ such that $f(t+a)-f(t)=b$, and you want to find $t$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(t) = f(t+a)-f(t)-b$ is a known polynomial of degree one lower than the degree of $f$. You are looking for the value(s) of $t$ for which $g(t)=0$. So you can approach this just like you would approach finding the roots of any polynomial. For example, if $f$ is cubic, then $g$ is quadratic and you can use the quadratic formula. In general, finding roots of high-degree polynomials can be hard, but that's what you have to work with.